# What does SYSTEM mean in `<!DOCTYPE people SYSTEM "peopleDTD.dtd">`?

Tags: xml

What does SYSTEM refer to or mean in `<!DOCTYPE people SYSTEM "peopleDTD.dtd">`? It just seems to be standard usage in XML docs and DTD's, but don't know what it actually means. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The SYSTEM keyword indicates that the SGML processor should locate the DTD in a system specific fashion. This typically (but not always) means the DTD will be provided as a filename.

— [FreeBSD Documentation Project Primer for New Contributors - SGML Primer](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/fdp-primer/sgml-primer-doctype-declaration.html)

Comment: Thanks, @Quentin! I did a search on google and did not come up with that answer. I appreciate it.